# How do I access each value of a JSON object?

Tags: php, json

How do I access each value of a JSON object that contains an array of dates? Im sending a JSON Object from my android app.

```
{"date":"[Tue Apr 05 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016, Wed Apr 06 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016]"}
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

if(isset($_POST['ngno']) && isset($_POST['JSON']) ){

   $ngno = $_POST['ngno'];
   $json = json_decode($_POST['JSON'], true);
   $dates = $json['date'];

   foreach($dates as $date){
        $job = $db->updateDates($ngno, $date);

        if($job){
             $response["error"] = FALSE;
             echo json_encode($response);
        }

        else{
             $response["error"] = TRUE;
             $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in Updating!";
             echo json_encode($response);
        }
   }

}

else{
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Dates are missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);    
}
?>
```

`updateDates` function:

```
public function updateDates($ngno, $date){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO datepicker(ngno, date) VALUES($ngno, $date)");
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

But I get an error saying, PHP Warning:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: check `print_r($json)`

Comment: `$json["date"]` is not an array it is a string.

Comment: [Tue Apr 05 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016, Wed Apr 06 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016] is a string. I guess you need to explode it on `,` and strip out `[` which sounds like you're sending the wrong data.

Comment: *"How do i access each value of a JSON object?"* You don't. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. As of `$json = json_decode($_POST['JSON'], true);`, you're not dealing with JSON anymore, your `$json` variable refers to a PHP associative array.

Comment: Step 1 is to have your Android app send something more useful. Currently the `date` field it's sending is a *string* starting with `[` and ending with `]` with textual dates in it. It would be rather more useful for it to provide the value of `date` (which really should be `dates`, as it's clearly meant to have multiple values) as an *array* containing a standard date string such as ISO-8601, or a since-The-Epoch value.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say you're currently trying to loop through a `string` and not an `array` so that's why the `foreach` is giving you back an error.

The **good** solution would probably be to alter your set up so your `JSON` returns an `array` of dates rather than a `string`.

The **other** way to solve this would be to explode the `string` into an `array` like so:

`$dates = explode(',', $json['date']);`

That way you have an array you can loop through.